# Setting SQL Server Session Context from SSIS Transfer SQL Server Objects Task

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to run a SSIS Transfer SQL Server Objects Task under a SQL Server session context.  A function provides a default value for tenant id column that is obtained from the session context.  I cannot find a way to set the session context so that it is available to the task.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Why would you need the session context during the Transfer SQL Server Objects Task?  In any case the Transfer SQL Server Objects Task is only a wrapper for the SMO scripting library which you can use from a Script Task or a PowerShell script.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.